# Replicate the same source folder to multiple end points, with a different schedule for each end point

Tags: windows, replication, dfs, dfs-r

I'm trying to make a set of folders (about 8 gig) that get updated monthly to replicate out to nine branch locations.  They are connected via VPN back to head office with 1.5Mbit aDSL links.
I've got Win Server 2008r2 at all ends.

I'd prefer to replicate the source to a couple of end points each night.  The head office bandwidth makes trying to update all nine at once not practical.  In addition, that way I might later be able to add some additional VPN tunnels to help branches replicate among themselves.

I've set up one replication group in 'backup mode' with 2 end points read-only, and a scheduled time block when it can update.

Now I'd like to add two more end points that run on a different (non overlapping) schedule.
You can't choose the same source for two different replication groups, even if the end points are read-only.

What's the best way to work around this?  I'd rather not duplicate the source folders if I don't have to.

EDIT:  On futher review, I see when you add another member you can choose a custom replication schedule and make that different than the schedule you set up the first time through.  What's confusing is you can't see that new second schedule ever again.   Once set up it just shows the initial replication group schedule.

I'm going to try and monitor it over the next couple days to see if it is actually using separate schedules for separate members, but it sure would be nice to prove the schedules I gave it are in there somewhere.  Suggestions here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at [Digionica SyncTool](http://www.digionica.com/Products). It's my project and as a developer I can give you free keys.
I wrote it specially for folder replication in LAN. It works as Windows service, has an inner sheduller and does not require shared folders.